Problem with dense set
On ' Set theory with an introduction to real point sets'(Dasgupta, Abhijit ,2014) i found this exercise:

This is interesting because compare the topological (left,1) and order (right,2) definition of dense set.
(1) $A$ is dense in $X$ if $X\subseteq \overline{A}$.
! Ps. I considered $X$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and then $\overline{A}$ is closure of $A$ (i.e. set of adherent  point of $A$)
(2)  forall $x,y\in X$ with $x<y$ there is $a\in A$ with $x<a<y$.
Recall also that: (3) $X$ is dense order if forall $x,y\in X$ with $x<y$ there is $z\in X$ with $x<z<y$.

My proof of 1)-->2): Let $x,y\in X$  with $x<y$.
For (3) exists $z\in X$ with $x<z<y$.
For (1) $z\in \overline{A}$. From definition of adherent  point exists  $c\in (x,y)\cap D$ and ok.

I have problem with 2)-->1) implication.
If i considered $X=[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ and $A=[0,1)$ then it seems to me that: $X$ is a dense order, $A$ verified (2) but not (1) ($\overline{A}=[0,1]$).
What am I doing wrong?

"tale que" sounds good.

By definition $493$ of Dasgupta, $2$ is indeed a limit point of $A$ considered as a subset of the order $X$.
Does the so called topological definition appear in the book? I couldn't find it. What are you doing wrong? Well, you are using a definition that doesn't appear in the book and in fact contradicts the definition appearing in the book. Different textbooks might (and very often do) use different definitions or conventions.

So the proposed definition of limit point and derived set does not coincide with the classical one? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)]. When this definition are equivalent? PS. Topological because i considered the 'Subspace topology' on $X$.
